# how to Merge similar item in list and aggregate the values in kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, collections

I got this json response

```
{
"status": [
    {
        "conferencing": {
            "nrOfRxBytes": 1142294,
            "nrOfTxBytes": 368502,
            "CategoryActiveTime": 9625,
            "Active": true
        },
        "social_media": {
            "nrOfRxBytes": 163156131,
            "nrOfTxBytes": 1438337,
            "CategoryActiveTime": 10406,
            "Active": true
        },
        "media_streaming": {
            "nrOfRxBytes": 5065342,
            "nrOfTxBytes": 312250,
            "CategoryActiveTime": 213,
            "Active": false
        },
        "Device": "BE:A0:FE:74:39:C1"
    },
    {
        "conferencing": {
            "nrOfRxBytes": 58534,
            "nrOfTxBytes": 24615,
            "CategoryActiveTime": 10343,
            "Active": true
        },
        "social_media": {
            "nrOfRxBytes": 5618,
            "nrOfTxBytes": 2731,
            "CategoryActiveTime": 14308,
            "Active": true
        },
        "media_streaming": {
            "nrOfRxBytes": 747,
            "nrOfTxBytes": 397,
            "CategoryActiveTime": 448,
            "Active": false
        },
        "education": {
            "nrOfRxBytes": 404,
            "nrOfTxBytes": 260,
            "CategoryActiveTime": 419,
            "Active": false
        },
        "Device": "AC:12:03:EC:9B:D1"
    }
]
```

}

i want to join similar catgories (education, conferancing...) together and aggregate the values of similiar fields and make a list of "Device" that are in that category

like this:

```
 [{
"name":"conferencing":
                "nrOfRxBytes": 1200828, // agg this 
                "nrOfTxBytes": 393 117, // agg this 
                "CategoryActiveTime": 19 968, // agg this 
                "Active": true, 
            "Device": ["AC:12:03:EC:9B:D1","BE:A0:FE:74:39:C1"] //this is a list of devices that are in the same category
},...]
```

I tried creating parcelized data class

```
    @Parcelize
    data class ServicesIdCategory(
        var name: String = "",
        val nrOfRxBytes: Int = 0,
        val nrOfTxBytes: Int = 0,
        val CategoryActiveTime: Int = 0,
        val Active: Boolean = false,
        var Device: String = ""
    ) :
        Parcelable
```

and then i parsed the the results to it and created a list of ServicesIdCategory

```
fun getLiveServicesId(response: JSONArray): Array<ServicesIdCategory> {
    val array = mutableListOf<DeviceServicesId>()
    var categories = mutableListOf<ServicesIdCategory>()
    var category = ServicesIdCategory()
    val gson = Gson()


    for (i in 0 until response.length()) {
        val obj = response.getJSONObject(i)


        val namesArr = obj.names()
        if (namesArr != null) {
            for (j in 0 until namesArr.length()) {

                if (namesArr[j].toString() != "Device") {
                    val categoryJson = obj.optString(
                        namesArr[j].toString(), ""
                    )
try {

                    category = gson.fromJson(categoryJson, ServicesIdCategory::class.java)
                    category.name = namesArr[j].toString()
 } catch (e: JsonSyntaxException) {

                    }
                  
                }
                category.Device = obj.optString("Device")
                categories.add(category)

            }
        }
        val deviceServiceId = gson.fromJson(obj.toString(), DeviceServicesId::class.java)
        deviceServiceId.servicesIdCategory = categories.toTypedArray()

        array.add(deviceServiceId)


    }
 
    return categories.toTypedArray()
}
```